# Google Play Services Imported but still gives error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libraries

UPDATE 1

Google Play Services has been imported the whole time. Here is the snip.

[image: gpsimported]

OP

I've had this running somehow for quite some time but again this issue comes up.  I reimported google_play_services once again and everything looks fine but I still get build path error when trying to export. 
No matter how many times i clean/build, this doesn't help.

[image: folders]

[image: google_play_services]

[image: libraries]

If you have any clue I would appreciate it greatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Android SDK Manager and install Extras → Google Play services
2. Import the library which was downloaded into Eclipse via File → Import → Android → Existing Android Code into Workspace.(path:eclipse\android-sdk-windows\extras\google)

To use this library define a library dependency in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have it working. These are my conclusions:
1. No body really knows how to import Google Play Services correctly. Because each development environment is different, so is the import process. This is dumb, there should be a logical mapping as to this procedure.
2. I have 2 workspaces at the moment, both working.
2.a First workspace imported the google play services library by NOT copying it into workspace. It's working.
2.b Second workspace imported the google play services library by copying it into workspace. It's also working.

Thanks all for responses.